# VBA - Submit - Input tag

Tags: vba, authentication, submit

I am trying to hit submit in this log in, in order to get our data from one of the pages, when I am logged in.

But I am super new to this, and I might be fare of track. But this is what I got. I am defining the submit as a form. Do not know why I, just change around in the info I got from a youtube video.

```
Sub clickFormButton()
Dim ie As Object
Dim form As Variant, button As Variant
```

this is where I try to press the submit button. With no success. The reason for the (2) is because it is input tag number 3 that got the submit.

```
Set form = ie.document.getElementsbytagname("input")
Set button = form(2).onsubmit
form(2).submit
```

http://login.tradedoubler.com/public/aLogin.action?language=en&country=GB

This it the page that I am trying to access.

As always, thank you in advance! It is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just replace this ...

```
Set form = ie.document.getElementsbytagname("input")
Set button = form(2).onsubmit
form(2).submit
```

...with this...

```
Set form = ie.document.getElementsbytagname("input")
For Each btn In form
    If btn.Value = "Login >" Then
        btn.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Why? Because you know that on the button there is always written "Login >", while you are not sure that the submit button will be always the third element of the input collection in the webpage.

Comment: Thank you! I really liked that you added the "Why?" part. Thanks again!